# Documentation stores pvt key and creates EthAdapter but how to do it from wallet

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I have been trying to create an EthersAdapter instance, but on the documentation provided by the safe protocol kit, they are storing the private key. But while making a dapp and incorporating a safe transaction while connected to a metamask wallet, how are you supposed to create a safeSdk instance without getting the private key of the owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option is to install all the required packages on the frontend itself. You can get the signer from the provider using metamask and then proceed further.